# Row from data source copied into multiple rows in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I used "copy with headers" from SQL Server Management Studio result pane of the data into Excel.  Strangely some source rows are copied by Excel as multiple rows. This doesn't happen to each single row. For those rows that should have been on the single row have an additional row inserted below the original. The additional rows are misaligned with the column headers. I modified the query to truncate the offending column so that only first 200 characters are shown without avail.

How to prevent copying data into Excel from being split so they appear in Excel as they are in Management Studio? Thanks.

[image: strange data copy]

Comment: Any extended characters such as Tabs or CRLF's ?

Comment: No.  I don't think so.

Comment: I suspect Acute or chronic renal failure.  It looks like this is where it breaks.   Copy that cell from SSMS and paste it in a text editor or an empty console tab.   Does it produce more than one line?

Comment: Perhaps  Replace(Replace(admintdx,char(10),' '),char(13),' ')

Comment: ah, John Cappelletti's statement works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Replace(Replace(admintdx,char(10),' '),char(13),' ')
```

to remove any extended characters